# swift firebase iterate each snapshot value to update / set a value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

Im trying to fetch all data from firebase database and update or set(if nil) each value differently. for example i have 5 users:

[1-jon likedby:jef, 2-jef likedby:nil, 3-jake, 4-mat, 5-taylor likedby:jon]

It should update/set each value differently (when button pressed update/set value and go to next value.

my code shows that i could iterate but i have no ideas on how to set each value.
 or is it not possible in firebase snapshot ? if so please advice/suggest on other or similar methods to solve the problem.

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print("##########")
        var dictionary = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]

        for(_,value) in dictionary{
            if let firstKey = snapshot.key as? String{

                var likedby = value["Liked By"] as? String
                let name = value["name"] as? String
                let age = value["age"] as? String
                let caption = value["caption"] as? String
                let picURL = value["photoURL"] as? String
                let gender = value["gender"] as? String
                print("TTT")
                print(name, "was liked by",likedby)

                if likedby == nil || likedby != "Othman" {
                    print("****")
                    print(name)
```

Answer (score 3):

A Firebase `DataSnapshot` is *read-only*. It's mostly used to read back data previously fetched from Firebase.

You need to use [`DatabaseReference.setValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-setvalue) method instead to *update* a given node. As mentioned in the comments, the [`DataSnapshot.ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#ref) property provides a handy way to get back a `DatabaseReference` corresponding to a given snapshot.

Comment: You can get the `FIRDatabaseReference` for a snapshot through its `ref` property. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#ref

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Nice hint, thanks! Totally forgot about the handy `ref` property...